# Modify some properties of all objects inside an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, ecmascript-6

Having this array of objects:

```
const input = [{ name: 'a', access: true, type: ""}, 
               { name: 'b', access: false, type: "XYZ"},
               { name: 'c', access: false, type: ""},
              ];
```

I want a method to modify some of the properties of the objects while not affecting the others. For example, all the `access` to be set on `true` and all `type` to be `"TEST"`.

Tried with map and other methods but didn't work:

```
const result = input.map(a => {a.access = true, a.type = "TEST", ...a});
```

The result should be:

```
result = [{ name: 'a', access: true, type: "TEST"}, 
          { name: 'b', access: true, type: "TEST"},
          { name: 'c', access: true, type: "TEST"},
         ];
```

Answer (score 2):

Should first do `...a` and then replace the properties. Also instead of `a.access = true` it should be `access:true`

```js
const input = [{
    name: 'a',
    access: true,
    type: ""
  },
  {
    name: 'b',
    access: false,
    type: "XYZ"
  },
  {
    name: 'c',
    access: false,
    type: ""
  },
];


const result = input.map(a => {
  return {
    ...a,
    access: true,
    type: "TEST",

  }
});
console.log(result)
```